Electron build incorrect (missing icon and code)

I turned half the Internet over in search of a solution to the problem and the solutions that I found did not help me.
When testing the application, the icon in the tray as well as the code works fine, but after compiling the code in the application, the icon in the tray does not appear (and the application itself), and the icon in the folder with the application does not change (the application icon is set to the standard one as in Electron itself)
When I use npx @electron/packager ., the application starts, but the icon still doesn't change. At the same time, if I use npm run package, then the application doesn't start at all, and there is no icon in the application folder.
"package": "electron-packager . \"Wifi Batttery Status\" --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Wifi Batttery Status\""

Screenshots:
package.json
directory

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
